# Dropzone.js addRemoveLinks not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4, dropzone.js

Hello I am having a problem using the custom options in Dropzone.js. It is not displaying the remove links even when I set it to true. I am not sure if I am going about this wrong or what exactly is happening. The files are uploading correctly and the loading bar & completed check mark show.

The current code I have is:

```
<html>

<head>   

<!-- 1 -->
<link href="models/site-templates/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- 2 -->
<script src="models/dropzone.js">
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
};
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- 3 -->
<form id="myDropzone" action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's upload.php

```
<?php
$ds          = "/";  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds . "temp" . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare you dropzone initialization in its own separate script element and to remove the thumbnail add a removedFile method:-

```
<script src="./lib/dropzone-3.12/dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function(file) { 
      var _ref;
      return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Call :

```
file.previewElement.remove();
```